# Computing ${\partial U \over \partial x}$ and ${\partial U \over \partial y}$ for $U(z)= \int_\gamma (z - a)^n\ dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

**Goal:** Let

$$
U(z)= \int_\gamma (z - a)^n\ dz
$$

I'm trying to compute ${\partial U \over \partial x}$ and ${\partial U \over \partial y}$.

**Attempt:**

1. I know that $(z-a)^n$ is the derivative of $(z-a)^{n+1}/(n+1) = F$.
2. Yet $(z-a)^{n+1} / (n+1)$ is analytic.
3. Hence the Cauchy-Riemann equations yield that ${\partial F \over \partial x} = (z-a)^{n+1}$ and ${\partial F \over \partial y} = -i (z-a)^{n+1}$
4. **Yet $U$ and $F$ can vary only by a constant (is this correct?  why?)**
5. Hence $U$ and $F$ will have the same partial derivatives.  Hence

   $${\partial U \over \partial x} = (z-a)^{n+1}$$

   and

   $${\partial U \over \partial y} = -i (z-a)^{n+1}$$

**Question:** Is my assesment correct (in particular, with $(4)$)?

Comment: This question probably has a typo. Note that the RHS of $U(z)= \int_\gamma (z - a)^n\,\mathrm dz$ is a number, therefore $U$ is constant and every thing is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

I understand from context that $\gamma$ is a contour ending at $z$. The definition of $U$ would be better stated as
$$U(z)= \int^z  (\zeta - a)^n\ d\zeta$$
You  correctly noted that $U$ agrees with $(z-a)^{n+1}/(n+1)$ up to a constant; this is the fundamental theorem of calculus for line integrals. But your differentiation of $F$ contains a mistake. The exponent of $(z-a)$ in the derivatives should be $n$, not $n+1$.

Actually, we do not have to find an antiderivative of $(\zeta - a)^n$ explicitly. We know it exists locally. Just call it  $F$. By definition of antiderivative, $F'(z)=(\zeta - a)^n$. Then write down what this means in terms of partial derivatives (Cauchy-Riemann equations, etc), and you are done.